# Makefile for multiple C programs

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I've got a task to do a makefile of 5 different c programs. Let's call them `1.c, 2.c, 3.c, 4.c, 5.c`
The code i've got is:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS =
OBJFILES = 1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o 5.o 
TARGET = 1 2 3 4 5

all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES)
```

And the feedback is that I should do something with static template. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You don't want to have every program linked with every object file.  Make knows how to build a program from a single source file.  Remove the two lines above the `clean:` line.

Answer (score 4):

You should let Make use its default rules.  Your entire Makefile can be as simple as:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

all: 1 2 3 4 5
```

But if you are willing to require the user to type `make 1` and `make 2`, etc., you can just delete the makefile completely.  Let the user specify CC and CFLAGS in their environment if needed/desired.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by a static template, but your Makefile does not work. Try this change instead:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $@.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

The drawback is that it compiles all five programs even if only one has to be rebuilt.